# Pandas: how to concatenate rows with conditions (number of characters)?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe looking like this:

```
column_text
"this is line 1"
"this is line 2"
```

I would like to have lines having around 900-1100 characters.
Example:

1)If len(row1) < 1000 -> concatenate with next row
2)If len(row1 with row2) < 1000 -> concatenate with next row
If at row4 I achieve len around 1000, for the row 5 same steps (1 and 2)
And so on.

Is there a good way to do this with Pandas?

Answer (score 3):

I think this would work:

```
approx_row_length = 950

df['char_group'] = df.column_text.str.len().cumsum().floordiv(approx_row_length)

df.groupby('char_group').column_text.sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are many ways to do this with Pandas. My solution is to use a for loop.

1. Import module

```
import pandas as pd
```

2. Create raw data

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'column_text':['this is line 1', 
                    'this is line 2',
                    'this is line 3',
                    'this is line 4',
                    'this is line 5']}
)
```

3. Get results

```
new_column = list() # Create an empty list to store concatenated rows.
temp = '' # Create an empty string to temporarily store strings.

for row in df['column_text']:
    temp = temp + row
    if len(temp) >= 20:
        new_column.append(temp)
        temp = ''
        
pd.DataFrame({'new_column':new_column})
```

**Result**:

|  | new_column |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | this is line 1this is line 2 |
| 1 | this is line 3this is line 4 |